# Keycloak Custom SPI Authenticator - KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Keycloak version 18

Purpose: I want to store scope parameters in user session notes to be later fetched in my custom protocol mapper. To do the same I am referring to [this](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-May/018393.html) blog post which talks about creating a custom JS authenticator, however, as I prefer Java, I tried implementing the same in java.

I can see the custom authenticator, in my keycloak server-info and during setup.

Here is my implementation:

```
public class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticator.class);

@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    log.info("authenticate :: START");
    try {
        AuthenticationSessionModel authenticationSession = context.getAuthenticationSession();
        String sessionClientNote = authenticationSession.getClientNote("scope");
        log.info("client note from auth session : " + sessionClientNote);
        authenticationSession.setUserSessionNote("scope", sessionClientNote);
        context.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INTERNAL_ERROR,
                context.form().setError("smsAuthSmsNotSent", e.getMessage())
                        .createErrorPage(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
}

@Override
public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    log.info("No Custom Action is set.");
    context.success();
}

@Override
public boolean requiresUser() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean configuredFor(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, UserModel user) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setRequiredActions(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, UserModel user) {
   log.info("No required actions are set.");
}

@Override
public void close() {
}
```

}

```
public class MyAuthenticatorFactory implements AuthenticatorFactory {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "my-authenticator";
    
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

@Override
public String getDisplayType() {
    return "MY Authentication";
}

@Override
public String getHelpText() {
    return "Will read the scope parameters and store in user session";
}

@Override
public String getReferenceCategory() {
    return PasswordCredentialModel.TYPE;
}

@Override
public boolean isConfigurable() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isUserSetupAllowed() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
    return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
}

@Override
public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public Authenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
    return  new MyAuthenticator();
}

@Override
public void init(Config.Scope config) {
}

@Override
public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
}

@Override
public void close() {
}
```

}

Here is how the authenticator is set up as the last step of execution :

[image]

However, I get this exception while trying to log in or test this via Postman. This is not even hitting the custom code that I have written but failing much before that. Is it?

```
 2022-08-01 10:52:21,721 WARN  [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (executor-thread-25) REQUIRED and ALTERNATIVE elements at same level! Those alternative executions will be ignored: [auth-cookie, identity-provider-redirector, null]
2022-08-01 10:52:21,721 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-25) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException: authenticator: my-authenticator
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:437)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:264)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1030)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:892)
```

And this is the line number. I don't understand this code and what is it trying to do? Mine is a simple authorization code pattern. Can someone please advise/review my code?

[image]

I have also set these flows at the client level.

[image]